# How the getter/setter implement when add a @property in category with @dynamic

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories

I add a property to my category and use @dynamic in my category implementation.
It seems work well.

```
@interface aClass (Properties)
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *p;
@end

@implementation aClass (Properties)
@dynamic p;
@end
```

I know @dynamic means tell The compiler not to automatically synthesize the getter and setter methods.but why above code could work without my getter/setter implementation?
is it provides by runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would compile (and link, provided you had an actual `@interface` and `@implementation` and not just a category). But it would crash at runtime if you tried to use the getter.

When you passed `@dynamic`, you promised that the getter would be available at runtime (not the setter; this is `readonly`). If you try to use the getter at runtime, you will discover that your promise was not fulfilled and you'll crash with an "unrecognized selector" message. `@dynamic` says "trust me." You then have to be trustworthy.

(Note that classes should always start with an uppercase letter.)

---

Ah, you mentioned it was CALayer. That changes everything. CALayer is magic. Well, not magic, but definitely special. CALayer catches unhandled selectors and turns them into dynamic properties (storing the values in a dictionary I think), just like you're seeing. It was a very clever idea, and back in 10.5, some of us thought maybe this would be the "new way." (It's a natural extension of how Core Data works.) I think Apple figured out that it's too clever because they haven't spread it to other classes.

I actually talked with some of the Apple devs about it a few years ago at WWDC. I wanted to know if it was safe to rely on. The folks I talked to didn't realize it was in there and didn't recommend it.

Comment: When I run my project ,it has not crashed.I create a category of CALayer,and add a frame property. my project has used the getter somewhere.

Comment: Is your property on `CALayer` called 'frame'? `CALayer` already has a property with that name, hence a getter exists, which is why you don't experience a crash.

Comment: It just a "frame" property with another name.I do a test in a new project,it crashed as Rob Napier said.I don't know what happened in my project……

Comment: Wow,that's perfect answer and solve my confusion! your answer worth more votes.really really thank you!